# How to verify presence of a image in webpage by using selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

I am using `selenium IDE 1.10.0`. I am trying to check presence of image in product categories. what command should i use to verify image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open selenium IDE in FF browser

Right click on the image, then you see `assertelementpresent` command, if you do not see this command then hover over Show all available command and select `assertelementpresent`

Check image [image: here]

Comment: Thanks Ankit i got answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
assertElementPresent //img
```

The second is xpath relative to image

Best way how to find out for yourself:

- Open Selenium IDE addon
- Right click the element you want to check
- Hover Show all available commands
- Try to find most suitable command
- use that command and see what happens

Comment: I am new to selenium IDE. Please can you tell me how to find target for 'assertElementPresent' **command**.

Comment: as stated in the answer. Does right click work for you? Just right click the element with selenium IDE open and select "all available commands. It should be there

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of doing that depending on your task (why you need this image):

1) you may wait for the image to perform some actions (e.g. wait for the button to click it): waitForElementPresent(locator). It uses timeout set in your Selenium IDE.
So when element appears, your script will execute next line. If it does not appear - this case should be processed somehow (e.g. using verify - see item 2)

2) if you need to know if image is there - you may use verifyElementPresent(locator) - it returns true or false (and you may store this value). If image is not present - test will continue running (this is important!)

3) if this image is critical - use what was suggested here already: assertElementPresent(locator) - if image is not there test will stop.

P.s. I hope you know what locator means. If not - find samples, it is easy